# Chosen Multiple Select - Unselect "All" option when selecting anything else, and vice versa

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm using **Chosen Multiple Select** with an "All" option.

[Referring to this](http://jsfiddle.net/qCzK9/1/)

Basically what I want to happen is the following:

1. If the user selects any option other than "All", I want "All" to be automatically unselected - **works** using this:

   ```
   if ($('#customTextFilterSelect option[value="ALL"]').attr('selected') == 'selected' 
           && $("#customTextFilterSelect option:selected").length > 1) {
       $('#customTextFilterSelect option[value="ALL"]').removeAttr("selected");
   }
   ```
2. I also want the opposite to work - if the user selects "All", I want other options to be automatically unselected. **not sure how to best implement**
3. And lastly, if the user unselects everything (manually, by clicking 'x'), "All" should automatically be selected. **kind of working**, but the placeholder comes back when "All" is selected as if length==0

   ```
   if ($("#customTextFilterSelect option:selected").length == 0) {
       $('#customTextFilterSelect option[value="ALL"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
$(function()
{
    var cSelect = $('.chzn-select').chosen();
    var allItem = cSelect.find("option[value='ALL']"); //reference to the "ALL" option
    var rest = cSelect.find("option[value!='ALL']"); //reference for the rest of the options
    var allItemAlreadySelected = true; //set a flag for the "ALL" option's previous state

    cSelect.change(function(event)
    {   
        if ($(this).find("option:selected").length == 0) //if no selection
        {
            allItem.prop('selected', true); //select "ALL" option
        }
        else
        {
            if (allItem.is(':selected')) //currently "ALL" option is selected, but:
            {
                if (allItemAlreadySelected == false) //if previously not selected
                {
                    rest.prop('selected', false); //deselect rest
                    allItem.prop('selected', true); //select "ALL" option
                }
                else //if "ALL" option is previously selected (already), it means we have selected smthelse
                    allItem.prop('selected', false); //so deselect "ALL" option
            }
        }
        allItemAlreadySelected = allItem.is(':selected'); //update the flag
        $('.chzn-select').trigger("liszt:updated"); //update the control
    });
});
```

Now, you don't need that placeholder at all bec. the control now never gets empty. So, to get rid of the placeholder, all you have to do is; add this attribute to your **`select`**.

```
data-placeholder=" "
```

It's value should have a **space**, otherwise choosen may overwrite it.

```
<select data-placeholder=" " id="customTextFilterSelect" multiple='multiple' style="width:350px;" class="chzn-select">
```

Here is the [**working code on jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yxC4J/).

Comment: Selected as answer, because of comments and placeholder info.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following javascript to do this.

```
$(function () {
    //Defining the 'ALL' as default option.
    var prevdata = ["ALL"];
    $('.chzn-select').chosen().change(function(e) {

        if ($(this).find("option:selected").length === 0) {
            $(this).find("option[value='ALL']").attr('selected', 'selected');
        } else {
            var cur_date = $(this).val();

            if ($(this).find("option[value='ALL']").attr("selected") == "selected" && $(this).find("option:selected").length > 1)
                $(this).find("option[value='ALL']").removeAttr("selected");

            if(( $.inArray('ALL', prevdata) == -1) && $.inArray('ALL', cur_date) > -1){

               $(this).find('option').removeAttr('selected');
                $(this).find("option[value='ALL']").attr("selected", "selected");
               }
        }
        $('.chzn-select').trigger("liszt:updated");

        //Storing the current processed value 
        prevdata = $('#customTextFilterSelect').val();
    });

});
```

Following is the jsFiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/qCzK9/7/